# firebase+ angular orderby query not working

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework

Am getting this error performing this query with firebase, well not error but it not returning anything.

This is the factory

```
.factory("items", function($firebaseArray) {
    var itemsRef = new Firebase("https//*****.firebaseio.com/comments");
     return $firebaseArray(itemsRef);
})
```

and in my controller this is how am calling .using the orderby property/attribute

```
.controller('tdCtrl', function($scope, FeedList, $firebaseArray, $firebase,
     $stateParams, dataStore, feedSources, $ionicModal, items) {

     $scope.items=items //working when am calling normally
```

but now i want get all the comment with the hashkey 3432  -- which is dynamic but used as 3432 for easier explanation

```
 $scope.items = items.orderByChild("hashKey").equalTo(3434).on("child_added",  
   function(snapshot) {
});
```

this is the post function

```
.........
$scope.comment.hashkey=3432;
$scope.items.$add(comment);
.............
```

Comment: The code looks good, but it's hard to see without an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. It might be best of you reproduce the minimal problem in a jsfiddle (or similar tool).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - guess read all docs before attempting anything with firebase , alot of deprecated code used by most blog tutorial , so docs first :)

```
var fireRef= new  Firebase("https//****.firebaseio.com/comments");
$scope.items = $firebaseArray(fireRef.orderByChild("hashKey").equalTo(id).limitToLast(10));
```